# how can I create nested dictionary when columns values will be keys (has common values)

Tags: python, dictionary

my dataFrame is similar as the image.
[image]

shape of my dataFrame is 7739x4
my aim is to create a dictionary something like:

```
values = {
    'Khulna':{
        'Bagerhat':{
            'BagerhatSadar': ['WardNo01','WardNo02','WardNo03','WardNo04','WardNo05','WardNo06','WardNo07','WardNo08','WardNo09'],
            'Mongla': ['WardNo02']
        }
    }
}
```

how can I implement this with pure python?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

#create your dataframe
data = {
    "division_name" : ["Khulna" for i in range(10)],
    "district_name" : ["Bagerhat" for i in range(10)],
    "upazilla_name":["BagerhatSadar" for i in range(10)],
    "union_name":[f"WardNo0{i}" for i in range(1,11)]
}
data["union_name"][-1] = "WardNo02"
data["upazilla_name"][-1] = "Mongla"
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
"""
desired : 
values = {
    'Khulna':{
        'Bagerhat':{
            'BagerhatSadar': ['WardNo01','WardNo02','WardNo03','WardNo04','WardNo05','WardNo06','WardNo07','WardNo08','WardNo09'],
            'Mongla': ['WardNo02']
        }
    }
}
"""
values= {}

unique_division_names = df["division_name"].unique()
for i in unique_division_names:
    district_name_data = df[df["division_name"] == i]["district_name"].unique()
    values[i] = {j : None for j in district_name_data}
    for j in district_name_data:
        upazilla_name_data = df[(df["division_name"] == i) & (df["district_name"] == j)]["upazilla_name"].unique()
        values[i][j] = {j : None for j in upazilla_name_data}
        for k in upazilla_name_data:
            union_name_data = df[(df["division_name"] == i) & (df["district_name"] == j )& (df["upazilla_name"] == k)]["union_name"]
            values[i][j][k] = union_name_data.tolist()
print(values)
```

I wrote a bit long, but I set up the logic in this way, you can organize it by dividing it into functions or by any other method that comes to mind, without the clutter of code.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing in pandas that will provide this directly.

Comment: is it possible to do that without pandas. sorry my previous comment should be negative and i dont want to use pandas. thanks in advanced